# Capture user last login date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I log a users last login date? I've tried using `$query = "UPDATE users SET lastlogindate = NOW() WHERE username = "username"` to test it works but nothing unfortunately. I want to obviously ensure I log the date for the authenticated user correctly also.

Where should I put it in this script?

```
<?php 
    require("config.php"); 
    $submitted_username = ''; 
    if(!empty($_POST)){ 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email 
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try{ 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
        $login_ok = false; 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row){ 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']);
            } 
            if($check_password === $row['password']){
                $login_ok = true;
            } 
        } 

        if($login_ok){ 
            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']); 
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
            $query = "UPDATE users SET lastlogindate = NOW() WHERE username = "deason";
            header("Location: main.php"); 
            die("Redirecting to: main.php"); 
        } 
        else{ 
            print("Login Failed."); 
            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
        } 
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax highlighting gives it away: it's a quoting issue. You're using double quotes for your string and your string value in your query.

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET lastlogindate = NOW() WHERE username = "deason";
```

should be:

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET lastlogindate = NOW() WHERE username = 'deason'";
```

Comment: Hi John, is the location of the query correct? It works when plummed into Mysql console as a query

Answer (score 0):

Normally you have to add quotes:

```
 $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `lastlogindate` = NOW() WHERE `username` = 'deason'";
```

Comment: Quotes are added automatically when using PDO's prepare. Backticks are only needed for reserved keywords of which there are none in that query.

Comment: Then you are using reserved keywords, or you have a scheme with obscure names. ;-)